# Shrub name request

Tags: identification

I bought a shrub in my last house but I can’t recall the name.it had green leaves with a white edge but whatever was most noticeable was the stems that were red and especially noticeable in the winter. Any idea what this bush name is.

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a photo of the plant? It's too difficult to identify without seeing what it looks like.

Comment: Please read the tag info of the identification tag - even without a photo, you can add a lot more details: Size if the shrub, descriptions of leaf shape and texture, flowers, fruit... You can always [edit] your post with more details.

Comment: Cornus alba 'elegantissima' or Cornus alba sibirica variegata spring to  mind...

Comment: Cornus alba 'Ivory Halo' also springs to mind. That one was common in the US trade 5-10 years ago. May still be, for all I know.

Comment: without a picture the question is unanswerable

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: The description in the question is rather vague. This is somewhat a stab-in-the-dark without more details from the asker.*

If you mention strikingly red branches and variegated foliage, I immediately think about [Cornus alba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornus_alba) or Siberian dogwood. Some other dogwoods also show red(-ish) young branches, but with variegated leaves I suspect C. alba. A collection of photos can be found [here](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cornus_alba).

Some Japanese maples are also known for their red branches, but their variegated forms often show hints of red in the white areas.